# $_POST not working for url variables

Tags: php, post

I think this is simple.very. but i think i am missing something. I have a link:

```
 website.com/page?variable=value
```

when i use `$_GET["variable"]` i get the value, but when i use `$_POST["variable"]` , i dont get the value?
Please Help.

Comment: That's because you're sending the values using the `GET` method. If you want to use `POST` method, create an HTML form and let the user submit it (or use AJAX to do the `POST`). Then you'll be able to access it with `$_POST`.

Comment: @AmalMurali its a link to a profile of a person. i dont want people to fill up the name of the person everytime they want to open his page.

Comment: Then why do you want to use `$_POST` in the first place?

Comment: i dont want the question mark and the variable value. doesn't look cool.

Comment: @SauravChaudhary `i dont want the question mark and the variable value`, then use `POST`!  i dont understand what the problem is..

Comment: @SauravChaudhary: You can use `.htaccess` to prettify the links. But before you do anything, I suggest you learn the basics of HTML. This is a good starting point: http://htmldog.com/

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behaviour.

`$_GET` is populated with data from the URL's query string (which is taken from the request's headers).

`$_POST` is populated with data from the request's body.

If you want to read data from the URL's query string, use `$_GET`.

Comment: there has got to be some way

Comment: @SauravChaudhary, You _seriously_ need to read the basics of HTML.

Comment: @SauravChaudhary — Why should there be? It makes no sense for there to be a way. It isn't even slightly useful for there to be a way. If you asked for data from X but got data from Y, that would just be confusing.